Recover Git changes that has not been added to index or commited
I accidentally ran git reset --hard on changes that has neither been added to git index nor commited, Is there a way to recover the changes?
I have looked through several possible solutions, but it seems impossible to recover. I tried git reflog command, but I could not find the changes.

There is slim chance you have the files open in an editor and when you switched focus to the editor when it asked you if you want to reload the file you said no.

You cannot recover them because git did know anything about them.
The only chance is using some file system recovery tool.
Edit: as suggested by @LeGEC, if you are using an IDE (like IntelliJ), you should have the opportunity to query the IDE's local history feature and so recover all the lost changes.

@SofiyullahiJamiu : also, you may check if your IDE or editor has a way to restore past version of your files

You are right. I edit my post with your sggestion.
